# In Jira, how do I convert a story into an epic?

Tags: jira

How do I convert a story in Jira into an epic?

I am having the exact problem that this person is having: http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257348581

Comment: As you might have noticed people in the forums ask the poster to supply more information such as screenshots, logs, plugins. You could do that, too.

Answer (score 52):

You can do this through the More Actions dropdown:

1. On the Story Page, select the "More Actions" dropdown
2. then choose the "Move" option
3. On the following dialog you'll be able to change the issue type to an epic

Answer (score 3):

Go to edit the story.  From the edit page (popup in my case) you can change the story type to "Epic".

Comment: But - how in this case do you set the "Epic Label".  I end up with "unnamed" when I do this.

Comment: Didn't work for me (maybe depending on Jira setup of our org).